# Binding 2 Dropdownlist in ASP.NET mvc c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

This is my first dropdown list in my view.:
[image: First dropdown list]

And this is my controller:
[image: My controller]

My problem is that whenever I click the available dropdown in my first dropdown list it should populate the data available on the one that I have clicked on the second dropdown list. But It has an error it will not proceed to the next line which the JavaSerializer. How can I fix my code like it will work. I don't know where is the problem is, whether in the ajax? or in my controller?

Comment: Add a Console.log(result); and edit your question with the result so we can see the object passed back.

Comment: Debugging on both server-side and client-side may help you troubleshooting. But the code to serialize data to json on server-side and parse it at client-side look redundant.

Comment: What error you are getting? Can you share the code ibn the post instead of image?

Comment: Yes :) I'll try to post the code. There is no error, but the value can't get in

Answer (score 0):

Please change the select as jQuery("#availability option:selected").val();
 - Change the ajax type as GET method in client side 
 - JavascriptSerializer not required
 - remove [httppost] tag from code behind 
 - check where any error is there in browser console.

and change $('#availability').push("" + this.name+ "");